# Golang Postgres pq формат даты

Tags: html, postgresql, golang

Есть база данных Postgresql, в ней табличка с полями типа date

```
journal=# show styleshift;
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "styleshift"
journal=# show datestyle;
  DateStyle  
-------------
 German, DMY
(1 row)

journal=#
```

Драйвер для доступа к БД
https://github.com/lib/pq

Формат даты который мне необходим 02.01.2006,он такой и есть в БД

```
journal=# select * from j_nar limit 2;
 id | id_patient | number_nar | date_open_nar | date_close_nar 
----+------------+------------+---------------+----------------
 34 |         33 | 777        | 01.03.2017    | 05.03.2017
 35 |         34 | 111        | 18.03.2017    | 18.03.2017
(2 rows)

journal=#
```

Из формы html приходят данные в таком виде:

> 2017-04-01

В базе хранятся уже так:

> 01.04.2017

С сервера на frontend вывожу следующим образом.

```
type ListNar struct {
    Id  int64 `json:"Id"`
    IdPatient int64 `json:"IdPatient"`
    NumberNar string `json:"NumberNar"`
    DateOpenNar string `json:"DateOpen"`
    DateCloseNar string `json:"CloseOpen"`
}

func ModelListNar(id string)[]*ListNar {
    query := "SELECT id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar FROM j_nar WHERE id_patient = " + id + " order by id"
    rows := db.Select(query)
    bks := make([]*ListNar, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(ListNar)
        rows.Scan(&bk.Id, &bk.IdPatient ,&bk.NumberNar, &bk.DateOpenNar, &bk.DateCloseNar)
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks
}
func ListNar(w http.ResponseWriter, rnd render.Render) {
    bks := ModelListNar(currentId.id)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(bks)   
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s \n", b)
}
```

На frontend получаю данные уже такого вида:

> 2017-04-01T00:00:00Z

В структуре у меня не указан формат поля time.Time.
Почему так происходит и как это исправить.

Comment: Какого типа у вас колонки `date_open_nar` и `date_close_nar` в базе данных?

Comment: date, в формате german, dmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем в коде много, начнём с вашего вопроса. Забирать дату из базы в строку неправильно. Конечно, строку вы в JSON не измените при энкодировании. Поля `DateOpenNar` и `DateCloseNar` должны быть модификациями типа `time.Time`. Например:

```
type myTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t myTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    s := t.Format("02.01.2006")
    return []byte(s), nil
}

func (t myTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return pq.FormatTimestamp(t.Time), nil
}

func (t *myTime) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case string:
        t.Time, err := pq.ParseTimestamp(time.UTC, v)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    case []byte:
        t.Time, err := pq.ParseTimestamp(time.UTC, string(v))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("can't read %T into myTime", v)
    }
}
```

---

Помимо этого, в вашем коде ужасная SQL-инъекция:

```
query := "SELECT id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar FROM j_nar WHERE id_patient = " + id + " order by id"
rows := db.Select(query)
```

Так сейчас даже на PHP не делают. Правильно делать:

```
query := "SELECT id, id_patient, number_nar, date_open_nar, date_close_nar FROM j_nar WHERE id_patient = $1 order by id"
rows, err := db.Select(query, id)
```

где id - `int64`. Помимо этого, вы не проверяете ошибки (что является в го смертным грехом), и ваш код не соответствует [стилю](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments).

Comment: Про sql инъекцию спасибо, исправлю. На ошибки проверять буду. По поводу Time.time я так и делаю, я так хотел получить нужный мне формат времени.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев Добавил реализацию интерфейсов `driver.Valuer` и `sql.Scanner`, чтобы оно автоматически читалось и записывалось в базу.